# Does anyone know of any surverys/statistics on the Bitcoin ownership demographics?

Tags: history, historical-trade-data

I've only been able to find stuff from coin.dance, but was wondering if any of you have stumbled upon better data.

Comment: Which "stuff" did you find on coin.dance?

Comment: @Prayank sorry, should've mentioned that: https://coin.dance/stats